# Testcontainers: Synchronizing on Logs after the Service Was Ready

Tags: java, testing, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I'm developing some component tests using Testcontainers. I can synchronize the tests on service readiness. However, once the service is ready, I need to prepare the fixture and run the tests until the fixture is fully loaded.

The container under test writes a log that I could use to understand when the fixture is fully loaded. However, I cannot find a method to synchronize on that log.

Does the Testcontainers library offer any utility for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a GenericContainer object type you can simply do something like this:

```
WaitingConsumer consumer = new WaitingConsumer();
container.followOutput(consumer, STDOUT);
consumer.waitUntil(frame -> 
    frame.getUtf8String().contains("STARTED"), 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Else you can process the entire log with:

```
container.getLogs();
```

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized that my question was not focused. I'm sorry. The real problem is that I need to wait for the log `STARTED`, for example, to appear _n_ times in the log.

Comment: I don't know if there's a function that does it out of the box. 
Maybe you should create a method that consumes the log output and verify that specific condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a log message wait strategy to achieve it.

```
public GenericContainer containerWithLogWait = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("redis:5.0.3"))
    .withExposedPorts(6379)
    .waitingFor(
        Wait.forLogMessage(".*Ready to accept connections.*\\n", 3)
    );
```

You can also create your own strategy by extending it from `AbstractWaitStrategy`.

Check [this page](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. However, I didn't asked how to wait for readiness ;)